# Installing an older version of cvxopt with Anaconda 2

Tags: anaconda, conda, cvxopt

I'm trying to install a version of cvxopt that works with Python 2.7. For some reason when I do `conda search cvxopt` it brings back the version that works for Python 3.5. As such, I tried the following command:

`conda install cvxopt==1.1.4`

Cvxopt 1.1.4 is compatible with Python 2.7, but I unfortunately received a `PackageNotFoundError`. Are there any other ways I can install a Python 2.7 compatible version of cvxopt via the Anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show what OS you are using.

The official conda-channgel is [this one](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cvxopt), presented in the [docs](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html).

```
conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
```

It provides binaries for python2.7 [too](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cvxopt/files).

**If you are on Windows by any chance**, you got no chance then checking out potential (inofficial) channels. Keep in mind, that those are binaries and if there is no provider of py27+win, there is not much you can do with this approach of install.

[Omnia's](https://anaconda.org/omnia/cvxopt/files) channel provide windows-binaries (including python2.7), although not officially (but it's a more popular channel working).

Additional remark: all cvxopt-version are supporting python2.7. Doing an install like:

```
conda install cvxopt==1.1.4
```

restricts the potential candidates (as only newer versions might be shipped)